# MongoDB - authentication failed

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm using Pymongo to connect to the a read only instance of my MongoDB replica set.

The problem with my code is that sometimes the query goes through, while sometimes, apparently for no reason and with the same code, i get an `Authentication failed error`:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed', ....}
```

I don't understand why is this happening, since i'm performing very basic operations and my connection string should be alright.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://root:MY-PASSWORD@MY-IP:27017/?authSource=MY-DB&replicaSet=replicaSetOne')
db = client.marketdata

cursor =  db['MYCOL'].find({'unix': {'$gte': 1611874500}})

for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```

Any kind of advice is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did it work before?

Comment: Review the server log for the reason.

Comment: Check and compare your mongod.conf  in all replicaSet instances , you may have some typo when defining the authentication method ...

Comment: Is `MY-DB` really the database where the user was created? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: Yes! The query sometimes works and sometimes gives the error, it appears randomly

Comment: @JayK23 Are you trying to read from a secondary node of the replica-set?